# как в коде прописать версию компилятора и стандартной библиотеки

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-2015

собираю dll. Хочется в код зашить проверку на используемый компилятор и стандартную библиотеку. Как это сделать?

Comment: В Visual C++ можно воспользоваться макро `_MSC_VER`.